# How can we show the Lorentz symmetry is not anomalous in $\phi^{4}$ theory?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, special-relativity, symmetry, regularization, quantum-anomalies

how can I show in a lagrangian with scalar fields and $\phi^{4}$ interaction, the energy-momentum tensor isn't anomalous?

Comment: How do you show in other cases that it *is* anomalous?

Comment: In string theory, Poncaire symmetry is anomalous except in the critical dimension if you use light-cone gauge (which is not manifestly Lorentz invariant). The way you show this is by computing the algebra of the Poincaire generators after quantizing the theory; there is a "central charge" term that only vanishes in the critical dimension. In a manifestly Lorentz invariant quantization scheme, Lorentz invariance is ok, but this problem turns up in another way (for example you may have to worry about the worldsheet conformal invariance).

Comment: If you can do the entire calculation beginning to end, including quantization and renormalization, and at every step the calculation is manifestly Lorentz invariance, then there basically *can't* be a problem (modulo subtle non-perturbative effects that you may be blind to in perturbation theory); if the symmetry is broken, there has to be a step where you are forced to break it.

Answer (score 1):

In general, when you have a global symmetry group, say $G$ you can detect an anomaly as follows; Promote the symmetry to background gauge. I.e. make the symmetry transformations local, but add a gauge field, say $A$, to absorb them. However, that field is a *background* gauge field, namely, it does not have any curvature and you do not sum over it in the path integral. Now your partition function is a function of $A$, $Z[A]$. Now do the suggested gauge transformation: $A\mapsto A^\lambda$. If the partition function does not return to itself but picks up a phase, $$Z\!\left[A^\lambda\right] = \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}\,\Phi[A,\lambda]}\;Z[A],$$ then $G$ is anomalous. If it does not pick up a phase, it is not anomalous (modulo some subtle cases, where the anomaly is hidden). This is equivalent to the question of whether the path integral measure is invariant or not. For example, in the ABJ anomaly, you can either go the standard way looking at how the fermionic measure transforms under the two $\mathrm{U}(1)$s or turn on background gauge fields for both of them and do gauge transformations. In both cases, you pick up the same phase.

Now in the example of $\phi^4$ and Lorentz symmetry, the way to go is make Lorentz symmetry into a background gauge symmetry -- essentially couple the theory to non-dynamical gravity, so you have:
$$ Z[g] = \int \mathrm{D}\phi \ \exp\!\left(-\int\mathrm{d}^dx \sqrt{g} \left[\tfrac{1}{2}g_{\mu\nu}\nabla^\mu\phi\nabla^\nu\phi + m^2 \phi^2 + \lambda \phi^4 \right]\right).$$
Obviously doing a gauge transformation, i.e. a local Lorentz transformation does not change the partition function, as every term is manifestly gauge invariant. Hence
$$ Z\!\left[g^\lambda\right] = Z[g], $$
and thus you do not have an anomaly.

By contrast, in the example of (bosonic) string theory (to connect to Andrew's comment on the question), when you take the gauge-fixed Polyakov path integral, couple to a background metric, $h$, you can always go to conformal gauge $h = \mathrm{e}^{2\omega} \hat{h}$, and your background gauge transformations become Weyl transformations. Doing such a gauge transformation, gives $Z\!\left[\omega+\delta\omega\right] = \mathrm{e}^{\Phi[\omega,\delta\omega]} Z[\omega]$, where $\Phi$ is proportional to $c$, the central charge. Therefore there there is an anomaly, unless $c=0$, which in turn implies that $d=d_\text{crit}=26$.

Comment: Thanks for a canonical answer! Can you explain a bit more as to why turning on non-dynamic gauge fields and checking if the partition function picks up a phase under the "fake" gauge transformation is equivalent to checking if the measure is invariant under the original global symmetry? Also, independent of that, turning Lorentz symmetry into a background gauge symmetry means that the gauge symmetry is diff. invariance?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way (particularly for $\phi^4$ theory where you don't have to worry about any subtleties like gauge invariance) is just to use a Lorentz-invariant method to compute and renormalize correlation functions. For example, use the path integral formalism, and use dimensional regularization. Then every step of the calculation is manifestly Lorentz invariant, and in the end you get a finite answer.

Comment: Sorry for a naive question but regularisation only helps you show the symmetry perturbatively, right? To show that it's not an anomaly, you need to show it for non-perturbative effects. So the question reduces to, as always (?), whether you can find a Lorentz invariant measure for the path integral, right? The symbolic $\mathcal{D}\phi$ doesn't make it manifest, no?

Comment: @DvijD.C. That's a good question :) It's true in principle that you can have non-perturbative effects leading to an anomaly, like you need to compute instanton corrections to see the strong CP problem in QCD. But... well... waving my hands... $\phi^4$ doesn't have the features that lead to that kind of problem (like massive chiral fermions). The "usual" anomies like the chiral anomaly can be seen at one loop (in fact the chiral anomaly can be computed exactly at one loop).